How to change size of sheet view in SwiftUI?
In my ContentView, I have a button that triggers the sheet of "AddNewFolderView", which is simply a text field with a couple buttons. However, the view is much larger than necessary and I can't seem to figure out how to change the size.
ContentView:
.sheet(isPresented: $showingAddFolderView) {
                    AddNewFolderView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.viewContext)
                }

AddNewFolderView:
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Folder Name")) { // Section for user to input folder name
                    TextField("Enter folder name", text: $folderName)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("New Folder", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Cancel") {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, trailing: Button("Save") {
                addFolder()
            })
        }
    }

Which ends up looking like this:

I have tried presentationDetents(), which did nothing. As well as .frame() in various locations which always ended up looking like this:

Any suggestions?

Does this help?

presentationDetents are the correct way of doing this. If you can't make them work you got a bug elsewhere in your code.

FYI you should use .sheet(item:) where the item is the new folder you want to add, then you can bind the name field to the actual item's name.

If you set a frame with maxWidth and maxHeight on the view being presented, then set .clear as the presentation background, the sheet area can be reduced to a small size:
.sheet(isPresented: $showingAddFolderView) {
    AddNewFolderView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.viewContext)
        .frame(maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 150)
        .presentationBackground(.clear)
}

However, you still see a shadow effect for the regular sheet size. This is more noticeable in landscape orientation than portrait:

Another way to implement the dialog would be as a layer in a ZStack, which would allow you to feature any content and styling you like.
Alternatively, if you want to stick to some kind of native modal presentation then you could consider using .fullScreenColor, with a full-screen background of your choosing. You might like to apply a clip shape and shadow effect to the foreground view too. For example:
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingAddFolderView) {
    AddNewFolderView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.viewContext)
        .frame(maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 150)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
        .shadow(color: Color(white: 0.7), radius: 20)
        .presentationBackground {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.ultraThinMaterial)
                .background(.black.opacity(0.2))
        }
}


